# Error graficando en ggplot

Tags: base-de-datos, r, ggplot2

Primero un dput de mi base

```
dput(base)
    structure(list(mes = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "03", 
    "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
    "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
    "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "04", "04", "04", 
    "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
    "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
    "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04"), dia = c("01", "02", "03", 
    "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
    "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
    "28", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
    "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
    "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"), 
        n = c(2, 6, 19, 22, 7, 2, 10, 7, 17, 11, 21, 4, 6, 13, 7, 
        12, 12, 11, 10, 3, 10, 6, 12, 15, 9, 5, 2, 7, 12, 8, 9, 17, 
        8, 2, 7, 13, 15, 15, 20, 18, 8, 17, 10, 18, 21, 11, 16, 4, 
        20, 20, 10, 8, 16, 13, 5, 19, 14, 11, 9, 1, 6, 16, 9, 2, 
        17, 10, 14, 14, 9, 6, 5, 11, 13, 17, 10, 23, 13, 9, 5, 19, 
        9, 13, 9, 9, 5, 12, 8, 16, 17, 4, 9, 2, 15, 12, 14, 22, 14, 
        11, 3, 13, 10, 13, 15, 14, 8, 1, 17, 16, 14, 11, 2, 1, 3, 
        15, 7, 6, 9, 14, 8, 6, 12, 5, 1), fecha = c("01-01", "02-01", 
        "03-01", "04-01", "05-01", "06-01", "07-01", "08-01", "09-01", 
        "10-01", "11-01", "12-01", "13-01", "14-01", "15-01", "16-01", 
        "17-01", "18-01", "19-01", "20-01", "21-01", "22-01", "23-01", 
        "24-01", "25-01", "26-01", "27-01", "28-01", "29-01", "30-01", 
        "31-01", "01-02", "02-02", "03-02", "04-02", "05-02", "06-02", 
        "07-02", "08-02", "09-02", "10-02", "11-02", "12-02", "13-02", 
        "14-02", "15-02", "16-02", "17-02", "18-02", "19-02", "20-02", 
        "21-02", "22-02", "23-02", "24-02", "25-02", "26-02", "27-02", 
        "28-02", "30-02", "31-02", "01-03", "02-03", "03-03", "04-03", 
        "05-03", "06-03", "07-03", "08-03", "09-03", "10-03", "11-03", 
        "12-03", "13-03", "14-03", "15-03", "16-03", "17-03", "18-03", 
        "19-03", "20-03", "21-03", "22-03", "23-03", "24-03", "25-03", 
        "26-03", "27-03", "28-03", "29-03", "30-03", "31-03", "01-04", 
        "02-04", "03-04", "04-04", "05-04", "06-04", "07-04", "08-04", 
        "09-04", "10-04", "11-04", "12-04", "13-04", "14-04", "15-04", 
        "16-04", "17-04", "18-04", "19-04", "20-04", "21-04", "22-04", 
        "23-04", "24-04", "25-04", "26-04", "27-04", "28-04", "29-04", 
        "30-04", "31-04")), row.names = c(NA, 123L), class = "data.frame")
```

Lo que quiero es graficar utilizando el parámetro scale_x_discrete de ggplot para que aparezcan en el eje x únicamente lo siguiente: 01-01, 01-02, 01-03, 01-04, es decir, el primer día de cada mes.
En teoría, debería funcionar con lo siguiente:

```
ggplot(base, aes(fecha, n, group=1)) +
    geom_line(colour="red", size=1.2) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=paste0(c("01-01", "01-02", "01-03")))
```

Pero como puede verse, no da el resultado deseado y sólo genera texto para las primeras observaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier orientación y comentario al respecto. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general, los `geoms` usan el orden en que las variables aparecen en el `dataframe` salvo en el caso de [`geom_line()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) (y creo que en el caso de los `geom_point()`debiera ser igual`):

> geom_path() connects the observations in the order in which they
>   appear in the data. **geom_line() connects them in order of the variable
>   on the x axis**

Es decir, el orden de los puntos que conecta cada linea esta determinado por los valores ordenados del eje `x`. Por esto el orden final sería alfo así `"01-01" "01-02" "01-03" "01-04" "02-01" "02-02" "02-03" ... "30-04" "31-01" "31-02" "31-03" "31-04"`.

Lo que puedes hacer para evitar esto, es transformar `fecha` en un `factor` con el orden esperado

```
base$fecha <- factor(base$fecha, levels = base$fecha[order(base$mes, base$dia)])

ggplot(base, aes(x=fecha, y=n, group=1,)) +
    geom_line(colour="red", size=1.2) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("01-01", "01-02", "01-03", "01-04"))
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo cómo pasaste de la variable "fecha" con el formato en que yo la tengo a tu formato. Sin embargo, tu respuesta me ayudó a entender lo que estaba mal con mi código. Saludos :)

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, edité mi respuesta y agregué algo más de información. Espero quede más claro. Saludos.